# RQT_Graph cmd_vel passthrough

Tags: ros, arduino, navigation, rqt-graph, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,!
I am troubleshooting a robot I am working on and for some reason the twist commands are not getting to the base. On ething I found that I think is out of the ordinary is this: [image: image description]
Is it normal that /cmd_vel is:

1. Coming from two different sources into the rostopic node?
2. Going through the Arduino node?
3. And that it has that little loop above the /arduino bubble in the arduino node?

Thanks for all your help in advance,

luketheduke

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210761/rqt_graph-cmd_vel-passthrough/) by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 285 on 2015-06-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That diagram you poseted looks like a valid ROS node graph architecture-wise; ROS topic is n-to-n, not 1-to-1. See other threads for example ([1](http://answers.ros.org/question/151421/multiple-subscriber-to-one-topic/), [2](http://answers.ros.org/question/187328/subscribing-to-multiple-nodes-publishing-the-same-topic/)) for more concept.

Depending on your application, however, your configration can be problematic since all topics are published under the same name `cmd_vel`. You could publish the same topic type (called `msg` in ROS) under different names so that the subscribers can differentiate what they really need.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on 2015-06-14**:
When I loaded `rqt_graph` later it looked normal again. Thanks for your help!
luketheduke